# T-SQL Correct Join approach for 2 tables when right table has nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

Feel like a dufus and missing something simple. Left table is `Employee`, with a column called `EmployeeCode`. Right table is `Invoices`, with a column called `SalesPerson`, and a `TotalAmount` column which holds a sale value.

In any given week, not all employees will have invoices. I need the query  to return ALL employees and return a  0 in the sales column if no invoice records exist for a given employee. Presently, my query only shows me the rows where there is an invoice with a matching employee.

Here is my flawed query attempt - it ONLY returns me the employees who had invoiced amounts.

```
SELECT 
   E.LastName,
   E.FirstName,
   E.DefaultDept,
   E.EmployeeCode,
   ISNULL(SUM(I.TotalAmount), 0) As Sales
FROM
   Employee As E 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   Invoice As I On E.EmployeeCode = I.Salesperson
WHERE
   IsTechnician = 1
   AND IsActive = 1
   AND PostDate >= '2014-08-25' AND PostDate <= '2014-08-31'
GROUP BY
   EmployeeCode, 
   LastName, FirstName,
   DefaultDept
ORDER BY
   LastName
```

Comment: Can you show a subset of your data, the desired output and the observed output?

Comment: You probably have something in your WHERE clause that is in the Invoice table, you need to move it to the ON

Comment: I am guessing that the PostDate is from the Invoice Table and having this in the where clause will cause the result set you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of the columns in your WHERE clause:

```
Where IsTechnician = 1
AND IsActive = 1
AND PostDate >= '2014-08-25' AND PostDate <= '2014-08-31'
```

Are from the `invoice` table, that could cause the behavior you are seeing.  If any of those columns are from the `invoice` table you will need to check for `NULL` or the desired value.  Example:

```
AND (PostDate IS NULL OR (PostDate >= '2014-08-25' AND PostDate <= '2014-08-31'))
```

Comment: That DID IT !!  Thanks 10 million :)